# Why doesn't the asset function work in Symfony 5?

Tags: php, symfony, twig, assets, symfony5

I installed Symfony 5 using the `$ composer create-project symfony/website-skeleton my_project_name` command with the intention of getting the most complete Symfony package possible.

After configuring my Controller and the routes, I started coding the Twig template using Bootstrap 4 via CDN and the page rendering worked normally.

When I decided to configure the Bootstrap files in my location and no longer via CDN, I realized that the `asset()` function did not return the path of the files stored in the "public" folder.

The same occurs with other files and directories located inside the "public" folder.

I checked my "composer.json" file and the asset is configured in the following version:

```
"symfony/asset": "5.1.*"
```

It is correctly installed in the "vendor" folder.

Here is an example of using the function in my code in the "base.html.twig" file:

```
href="{{ asset("bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css") }}
```

I redid the steps for installing the "asset" component following the instructions in the documentation below and I also did not get any results:

https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/asset.html

I would like to know if anyone has been through it and if they have any solution for it.

Thankful.

Comment: The code you provide expects that there is a file located in "public/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css". Is it the case? Could you please edit your question with this information?

Comment: Which paths are used instead? What have you tried to debug the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution to this issue by chance:

The error was related to the way I ran the PHP server. I was running directly from the `public/` directory.

Within `public/`, execute the following command:

```
$ php -S localhost:8000
```

In general, the system built in Symfony worked normally, except the `asset()` method (I only noticed this single flaw).

As a solution, it was enough to access the main project directory and run the server using the following command:

```
$ php -S localhost:8000 -t public/
```

I would like someone to supplement the answer with theoretical information on how this corrects the flaw, as I'm a beginner and my knowledge of servers is limited.

Answer (score 0):

By default "asset" does not come installed.

```
composer require symfony/asset
```

https://symfony.com/doc/current/templates.html

Answer (score 0):

For those who are using Symfony 6
I got the same problem to fix it i
just go to the config/packages/webpack_encore.yaml

```
framework:
assets:
    json_manifest_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/public/build/manifest.json'
```

replace it by

```
framework:
assets:
    version: 'v2'
```